# How to create App Into with images and a pager below?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to have a bunch of images that show how my app works and have a dot-type pager at the bottom, like the example below. What UI Element should I be using?

Is Android ViewPager suitable for this? how will be adding the small circles below which act like page numbers.

EDIT: After I posted this question, I found [this library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator). Would like feedback on how to do this from scratch.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you look thought the code at https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator you can get a nice feedback on how to do it from scratch. The lib uses a custom `View` , but you can emulate this kind of behavior with some existent views, for instance. Basically:

- Create a `LinearLayout` below your `ViewPager`. Set the orientation to `horizontal`;
- Put some `RadioButton`s in it (you can do it dynamically based on your adapter size);
- In your `Activity`, `Fragment` or whatever set a `PagerListener` for your `ViewPager`;
- This listener is provided by the `ViewPager` API and you can check and uncheck your `RadioButtons` according to the position in the `ViewPager` with the method `onPageSelected(int position)`, for instance.

There you go, a (very) basic `ViewPagerIndicator`.